# what is the meaning of [had ever known] when the subject is something instead of someone?

Tags: verbs, vocabulary

The original sentence is

> She had given him the only joy **his arid life** had ever known.

Usually the subject of the verb **know** is someone

but here

the subject of *[had ever known]* seems to be **his arid life**

so what is the meaning of *[had ever known]* when the subject is something instead of someone

I ony looked up the definition of ***know*** in the [Collins CoBuild dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/know) before posting my question

It seems that the only entry which is most similar to the experience of something is the number 6.

Comment: It could also have been something like "the only joy his life had ever seen". It's an idiomatic way of saying something like "the only joy his life had ever contained".

Comment: Did you look up the definition of *know*?  One of the meanings is "experience".

Comment: @stangdon As for other dictionaries, I find the precise meaning of know for my original sentence. They are entries 10 or 11in the [Oxford](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/know_1)(I think 11 is more possible.) and entry the first B1 in the [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/know) after reading your comment.